# Testcontainers in Windows environment on GitHub Actions: "Could not find a valid Docker environment. Please see logs and check configuration"

Tags: java, windows, maven, github-actions, testcontainers

We're using [testcontainers-java](https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-java) heavily in our [spring-boot-admin](https://github.com/codecentric/spring-boot-admin) project. Since we also want to be able to run our Maven build also on Windows, we added a `windows-latest` environment to our GitHub Actions Pipeline using a Matrix strategy build ([as supposed in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64036382/4964553)) like this:

```
name: build

on:
  push:

jobs:
  build:
    strategy:
      matrix:
        os: [ubuntu-latest, windows-latest]

    runs-on: ${{ matrix.os }}
    steps:

      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Set up JDK 1.8
        uses: actions/setup-java@v1
        with:
          java-version: 1.8

      - name: Build with Maven
        run: |
          mvn -B install --no-transfer-progress
```

Now our Testcontainers JUnit testcase failes with (see [full build log](https://github.com/codecentric/spring-boot-admin/runs/1845099515?check_suite_focus=true)):

```
[INFO] Running de.codecentric.boot.admin.server.eventstore.HazelcastEventStoreWithClientConfigTest
Error:  Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.877 s <<< FAILURE! - in de.codecentric.boot.admin.server.eventstore.HazelcastEventStoreWithClientConfigTest
Error:  de.codecentric.boot.admin.server.eventstore.HazelcastEventStoreWithClientConfigTest  Time elapsed: 0.877 s  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a valid Docker environment. Please see logs and check configuration
```

So any idea what we can do to fix that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is that in Windows Server there are only Windows containers activated per default (no Linux containers). [As Sergei Egorov stated](https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-java/issues/2960#issuecomment-774483241):

> The problem with windows-latest is that it uses Windows containers, not Linux containers. It means that Testcontainers itself works, but all the images that it starts are Linux-based and, in Windows containers mode, they obviously fail to start :)

A "fix" for that would be to have a GitHub Action environment with Linux containers enabled! But after some googeling this doesn't seem to be that easy. First I though LCOW (Linux Containers on Windows) would simply need to be enabled. But as [this great elaboration](https://github.com/src-d/metadata-retrieval/issues/53#issuecomment-545353264) states, it's not easy (or even possible) to activate LCOW on the GitHub Actions Windows env.

I digged deeper into the issue and found [that LCOW was officially deprecated in `20.10`](https://github.com/docker/cli/blob/master/docs/deprecated.md#linux-containers-on-windows-lcow-experimental)  in favour of WSL2, that brings in native Linux runtime and also [Docker for Desktop on Windows 10 already favours this approach](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/wsl/).

**BUT: We are on Windows Server 2019**, which is not Windows 10 Desktop. And on GitHub Actions we only have the server version in it's nano flavor. There's sadly [an open issue for the WSL2 support in Windows Server 2019](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/WSL/issues/678). And scanning the GitHub Actions [Windows Server 2019 docs](https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/blob/main/images/win/Windows2019-Readme.md) I found out that there's only WSLv1 installed right now.